# Material Card content overrunning icon bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI cards.  I have an icon bar at the bottom of each card.  The media in the card is overrunning the icon bar as shown in the image here:

[image]

Here is the code where I put together the components:

```
return (
  <Card className={classes.card} >
    <CardHeader
      avatar={
        <Avatar aria-label={authorAvatar} src={authorImg} className={classes.avatar}/>
      }
      action={
        <Fieldset className={classes.date}>
          {postDate}
        </Fieldset>
      }
      title={post.title}          
      subheader={
        <Link to={userUrl}>
          {authorName}
        </Link>
      }
    />
    <div>
      <CardContent >
        <div className={classes.content} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: DOMPurify.sanitize(bodyHtml)}}></div>
      </CardContent>
    </div>
    <CardActions className={classes.actions} >
      <IconButton
        className={classnames(classes.unliked, {
          [classes.liked]: this.state.liked,
        })}
        aria-label="Add to favorites"
        onClick={this.handleFavourite}
      >
        <FavoriteIcon />
      </IconButton>
```

Here are the classes:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  card: {
    marginTop: 20,
    sizing, maxHeight: 600,
  },
  content: {
    height: 50,
    marginBottom: 100,
    //paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
    //sizing, maxHeight: 50,
  },
  actions: {
    marginTop: 20,
    display: 'flex',
  },
```

How do I get these things to work nicely, where the content stops before the icon bar with an adjustable margin?

Comment: May you provide some https://codesandbox.io/ sample?

Comment: @ArthurRubens for now, I will just leave the question as is.  We should be able to figure this out easily without it.

Comment: What should happen with the overflow? Hide? scroll? or expand the card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the card to expand along with the content just remove the fixed height from the content styles and the maxHeight from the card styles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  card: {
    marginTop: 20,
    sizing
  },
  content: {
    marginBottom: 100
    //paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
    //sizing, maxHeight: 50,
  },
  actions: {
    marginTop: 20,
    display: "flex"
  }
}));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jp1xe?file=/demo.js

But if you want to keep them with a max height just add an overflow style to the content

```
  content: {
    height: 50,
    marginBottom: 100,
    overflow: 'auto',
    //paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
    //sizing, maxHeight: 50,
  },
```